# Android Studio, Tabs dont show when I run the project

Tags: android, android-studio, tabs, android-tabhost

I have Android Studio 2.2.2 and

I create a simple Project with one **TabHost** and one textview "hello world", then I run the project with USB concetion to my cellphone and when the app is runnig I cant see the TabHost,
 I can only see the "hello world" Textview....the tab is **missing**.

The project is very simple, only for show the problem.

*In the project `res/layout/activity_main.xml` you can see the TabHost very well

Thanks in advance

Example:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

---

**activity_main.xml (Relative Layout)**

[Layout Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQYpq.png)

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Post the main activity, what guide are u referencing when you wrote this?

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity

```
    th= (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.th);
    th.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tab1=th.newTabSpec("Tab1");
    tab1.setIndicator("Page");
    tab1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    th.addTab(tab1);
```

=/